# Dynamic dropdown using ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

My application gives users the option to choose from several dropdown menus and the third menu should be dynamic depending on the selection from the previous two menus.

I am using ng-repeat and ng-if to set the condition like this

```
// First dropdown menu
<select ng-model="letter" class = "form-control">
    <option ng-repeat= "letter in letters" value = "letter">{{letter}}</option>
</select>

<br>

// second dropdown menu
<select ng-model="number" class = "form-control">
    <option ng-repeat = "number in numbers" value = "number">{{number}}</option>
</select>

<br>

// third dropdown menu
<select ng-model="color" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="A1_color in A1_colors" ng-if= "letter = A & number = 1" value="{{A1_color}}">{{A1_color}}</option>
</select>

...

<select ng-model="color" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="B2_color in B2_colors" ng-if= "letter = B & number = 2" value="{{B2_color}}">{{B2_color}}</option>
</select>
```

In my controller, I have the lists like this

```
$scope.letters = {'A', 'B'};
$scope.numbers = {'1', '2'};

$scope.A1_colors = {'red', 'pink'};
$scope.A2_colors = {'blue', 'black'};
$scope.B1_colors = {'yellow', 'orange'};
$scope.B2_colors = {'white', 'black'};
```

So if the user selects 'A' from the first menu and '2' from the second menu, he should see the options for 'A2_colors' in the third menu. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right way" is pretty subjective. Is this just a smaller example of what will be a larger collection of letters, numbers and colors? Here is one way you could approach it where you won't have to create a whole bunch of `<select></select>` elements that you show or hide.

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.letters = ['A', 'B'];
        $scope.numbers = ['1', '2'];
        var colors = {
            'A1': ['red', 'pink'],
            'A2': ['blue', 'black'],
            'B1': ['yellow', 'orange'],
            'B2': ['white', 'black']
        };

        $scope.colorSelection = [];

        $scope.setColorSelection = function() {
            if ($scope.selectedLetter && $scope.selectedNumber) {
                $scope.colorSelection = 
                    colors[$scope.selectedLetter + $scope.selectedNumber];
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedLetter" 
            ng-change="setColorSelection()" 
            ng-options="letter as letter for letter in letters">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="selectedNumber" 
            ng-change="setColorSelection()" 
            ng-options="number as number for number in numbers">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="selectedColor" 
            ng-if="colorSelection.length" 
            ng-options="color as color for color in colorSelection">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! Yes it is a small example of a huge list of different colors and numbers and letters. My only concern with this approach is that it looks messy inside var colors[] because of how many items I have

Comment: can you explain how I would do it this way if I have a tuple inside the [] like so: 'A1': ['red' : 'dark', 'pink' : 'light']?

Comment: I have implemented your approach but the options are not displaying

Answer (score 3):

I think, why to use ng-repeat for `<select>` tag when angular have another directive ng-options. You should use ng-options instead of ng-repeat. Never the less, you can also use ng-repeat, but it's not good way to do standard coding.

Syntax for ng-options:

```
 <select ng-model="item" 
         ng-options="item as item for item in collection">
 </select>
```

Your problem will solved by following code:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="letter" 
            ng-options="letter as letter for letter in letters">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="number" 
            ng-options="number as number for number in numbers">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="color" 
            ng-options="color as color for color in colors">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: why is ng-options better than ng-repeat. Also can you show how to actually do dynamic dropdown based on previous dropdowns?

Comment: You can use ng-change. Create one function and call this function on ng-change and do rest in this function. I guess it make some sense.

Comment: When angular have directive ng-options then why to go with indirect mechanism ng-repeat.

Comment: `ng-options` also allows you to use non-string value types.

Comment: @Lex can you explain what you meant by non-string value types, why cant ng-repeat do that

Comment: When you use `ng-repeat` to build your select options you are manually assigning the `value` which must be a string. When you use `ng-options` to build your select options Angular builds it and you can use a string, int, even an object as the value.

Comment: @Lex Please refer to updated post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323965/dynamic-dropdown-select-in-angularjs-not-working